# How to create double and long text field from django models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

How to create a `double` field in mysql using django models. i run into this error and also how to create a `longtext` datatype with django

```
class Test(models.Model):
   maxcount = models.DoubleField(null=True) ## double DEFAULT NULL,
   cs = models.TextField()#longtext,
```

Error:

```
    maxcount = models.DoubleField(null=True) ##double DEFAULT NULL,
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DoubleField'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#bigintegerfield
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#floatfield

Use big int in a case when you want an Integer and decimal field.
Use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#charfield for Char field and set max and min parameters

Comment: what about tiny int?models.SmallIntegerField create small int and how to create float field in this case

Comment: Like a PositiveIntegerField, but only allows values under a certain (database-dependent) point. Values from 0 to 32767 are safe in all databases supported by Django

and in case if you want to use flot use FloatField :
FloatField uses Python’s float type internally

Comment: Hmm, Alternativelity i think the coumentation could have been much better in this case.Ty

Comment: It seems like part of the text here is missing.

Answer (score 16):

There is no `DoubleField` in Django but `FloatField` [[FloatField description in Django's Model field reference]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#floatfield) creates a `double` datatype in mysql.

Django's `TextField` creates a `LONGTEXT` type in mysql. There is no easy way to change `TextField` behaviour to create e.g. `MEDIUMTEXT` type in mysql. But one can create a custom model field to achieve that: [Writing custom model fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#django.db.models.Field.db_type)

Comment: what about tiny int? models.SmallIntegerField create small int and how to create float field in this case

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be needing DecimalField: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield. It works well with MySQL, and you could also use this for integer values.

Declare the fields in your models

```
balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default=Decimal(0.00))
```

Also, consider defining a decimal context to create your actual values like so:

```
# defined in the settings.py file.
DECIMAL_CONTEXT = Context(prec=6, rounding=ROUND_DOWN)
```

This will ensure compatible decimal objects through your application, and create values like this:

```
DECIMAL_CONTEXT.create_decimal(0)
DECIMAL_CONTEXT.create_decimal(500)
DECIMAL_CONTEXT.create_decimal(5)
DECIMAL_CONTEXT.create_decimal(0.50)
```