# Django seems to truncate strings in MYSQL's longtext type column

Tags: mysql, django, django-orm

I have a MySQL `longtext` field, that corresponds to the following field in a Django model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # some other fields
    my_long_text_field = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

The problem is that Django seems to truncate my string when I am trying to save data (a unicode string with around 40k characters) to database. I have come across a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32516026/how-to-create-double-and-long-text-field-from-django-models) where they say that models.TextField corresponds to MySQL `longtext`.

Then why does this data truncating happening ? What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: To easyfy the awnsers, try to post the clean unicode data and how it became after stored in database.